# SQL Server - How to find the rows that have a value that contains a lowercase letter?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains a few columns which can have older values in the lower case.
I want to update these values to Upper case in case they exist.
At the DB level, the collation used is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` How should I write a query in an SQL server to achieve this?

Comment: Just update the column(s) and use `upper(columnName)` ?

Comment: Though you *could* add a `WHERE` to ensure that you only update rows where the value has a lowercase letter you would have to scan the entire index anyway, as using `COLLATE` on a column in the `WHERE` isn't SARGable, so there may not be much of a benefit.

Comment: Why do you want to make them uppercase? The collation is case-*in*sensitive. This means there's no difference between `potato` and `POTATO`. This also means there's no easy way to select just `potato`.  If you want to change how the values are displayed, the best place is the client application. Or an UPPER in the SELECT clause

Comment: Or, perhaps, you could add a computed column that is defined as `UPPER(YourColumn)`, and return that in your `SELECT` statements.